# Create many Eigen::VectorXd from one block of memory at once

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a big `m`-by-`n` chunk of memory that can be thought of `m` vectors of length `n`. I would now like to loop over all vectors and modify them. A double `for` loop would do, but I found that `Eigen::VectorXd`s are faster than hand-written loops. The following works (with dummy data `a`):

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  const int m = 100;
  const int n = 70;
  std::vector<double> a(m*n);
  auto data = a.data();

  for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
    auto r_i1 = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(&data[(i-1)*n], n);
    auto r_i = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(&data[i*n], n);
    auto x = r_i + r_i1;
    auto z = x - r_i;
    auto y = (r_i - (x-z)) + (r_i1 - z);
    r_i = x;
    r_i1 = y;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now, I'm wondering if it's possible to speed this up even further. It seems less than ideal to me, for example, to recreate `Eigen::Maps` from `data` chunks in each individual step.

Is it possible create a bunch of `Eigen::VectorXd`s from a large chunk of memory at once?

Comment: Why not use a `MatrixXd` instead of  the `std::vector<double>`? Then you have access to the rows and cols. Alternatively, you can make an `Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>` for `data` and use the rows and columns that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @AviGinsburg's suggestion, treating the block as an `Eigen::MatrixXd` works. Watch out for the column-major ordering in Eigen!

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const int m = 100;
  const int n = 70;
  std::vector<double> a(m*n);
  auto data = a.data();

  auto r = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(&data[0], n, m);

  for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
    auto x = r.col(i) + r.col(i-1);
    auto z = x - r.col(i);
    auto y = (r.col(i) - (x-z)) + (r.col(i-1) - z);
    r.col(i) = x;
    r.col(i-1) = y;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```